# SP2013 Custom list: Customize group order/sequence

Tags: 2013, custom-list, custom, grouping, ordering

I have a huge custom list with several columns. They are grouped by e.g. Status, but the order of the groups cannot be influenced as it is strictly alphabetical. Is there a (nice) way how to customize the order of the groups within the list without using prefixes for the Status, e.g. 1_Initiated, 2_Started, 3_Completed?

Comment: Are u want to group by alphabetically without using number prefixs like Completed, Initiated, Started? am i right?

Comment: I want to order it by myself. Without prefixes. But the only thing available OOTB is "order alphabetical" ascending/descending. I want to order the groups by myself, freehand so to say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a hidden column where you have a calculated column with an IF statement giving each value e.g.

`IF([Status]="Initiated",1,(IF([Status]="Started",2,IF([Status]="Completed",3)))` and so on. Use this then to order the group.

Comment: Thanks alot, I think this solved my issue in a nice way! Your help was highly appreciated.

Comment: One last question: Sharepoint does not let me "Hide" the Calculated column, it seems it is not allowed? The selection for the content type is not greyed out, I simply cannot click "Hide" as type.

Answer (score 0):

Look at how quick launch links are ordered in SharePoint or how columns are ordered in a view.  This is the closest SharePoint comes to having a user customizable order.  And STILL this functionality is not available as a column type for a list or library.

So, sorry, NO this is not possible with OOTB SharePoint.

But, in a post by [Stump the Panel from 2009](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2009/03/30/create-a-custom-sort-order-in-a-sharepoint-list-aspx/) they prove you CAN do this if you start with a link list!
[image]

Comment: Thanks for you input, I think the solution suggested by Ciara is even more elegant, but I will try the link-version as well!